# How to add sudo to grep and remove command?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to use the following command, but it requires to run `sudo` to work, how can I do that?

```
cd /usr/local/bin && \
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

Comment: Can you not `sudo su` into a root shell?

Comment: I guess I can, but I want to know where to add it into the line.

Comment: That depends which command is requiring it?

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Are you trying to remove any symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` which have `../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` as their target? Because there are *hugely* better ways to do that.

Comment: well done for catching that! I totally missed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *horrible* way of deleting any symlinks in in `/usr/local/bin` that point to `../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`.

It parses `ls` (see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for why you don't want to do that).

It uses `grep` which will, in theory at least, catch more than intended.

It isn't safe/going to work correctly if the filenames found have spaces in them.

It is also wildly over-complicated for the task.

Try this:

```
find /usr/local/bin -lname '*/../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7*'
```

and if that prints out the names of the things you expect (add `-ls` to the end to get `ls -l`-style output instead) then use

```
find /usr/local/bin -lname '*/../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/*' -delete
```

to remove them (assuming OS X `find` supports `-delete`).

If it doesn't use `-execdir rm {} \+` or `-execdir rm {} \;` or `-exec rm {} \+` or `-exec rm {} \;` (in that order until you find one that works).

Using `-okdir` or `-ok` instead of `-execdir` and `-exec` will cause `find` to print the command it wants to run at you for confirmation before running it (similarly `rm -i` will prompt for each file to be removed).

You can then use `sudo` on the entire `find` command or just the `rm` command as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't find anything for me. I also tried remove `..` before `Library/..`

Comment: Do you know that you have something in `/usr/local/bin` that needs to be removed? Can you run `ls -l` on it to see what it *actually* links to?

Comment: Yes there are files, e.g. 2to3, pip, python etc.

Comment: With my original command, I found `sudo xargs rm` or `xargs sudo rm` both seems to be working.

Comment: I found the way that works `find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/*' -delete`

Comment: Updated post to include start and end wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it is `sudo cd` that is giving you the trouble.

You can either `cd /usr/local/bin` then run `sudo ls -l ...`

OR

It looks like `cd` isn't really needed since you specify the path. So leave out the `cd` command and use full paths everywhere.

Comment: The `&&` is breaking up the list so `sudo` only affects the `cd` assuming `sudo cd ... && ls ...`.

Comment: Yea, that's why I say to do it separately.

Comment: My point was that `cd` itself isn't involved. *Anything* in a `&&` or `||` list will have the same effect.